# Generate table only after choosing the dates in the daterange

Tags: r, shiny

When you run code below, you will notice that a table will be generated automatically. However, I would like to generate this table only after choosing the start and end dates of my `dateRange`. How can I do this? I inserted an executable code below for you to test.

Thanks in advance!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange'),
                                 br()
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table'),
                                 br(), br(), 
                                 downloadButton("dl", "Download")
                               ),
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    tagList(dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                   start = min(data()$date2),
                   end   = max(data()$date2),
                   min   = min(data()$date2),
                  max   = max(data()$date2),
    
            tags$script(HTML('
                setTimeout(function(){
                  $("#daterange1 input")[0].value = "No date selected";
                  $("#daterange1 input")[1].value = "No date selected";
                }, 50);
            '))))
  })
  
    data_subset <- reactive({
      req(input$daterange1)
      days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
      subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
    })
    
    
    
  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    data_subset()
  })
  
  output$dl <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { "data.xlsx"},
    content = function(file) {
      writexl::write_xlsx(data_subset(), path = file)
    }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I preferred your version of the app, but here is the solution, if you take out the start and end the user has to know beforehand the dates to pick, you can aleviate this by messaging good starting dates but anyway...

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)

Test <- structure(list(date2 = structure(c(18808, 18808, 18809, 18810
), class = "Date"), Category = c("FDE", "ABC", "FDE", "ABC"), 
coef = c(4, 1, 6, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  shiny::navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
                    br(),
                    tabPanel("",
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 uiOutput('daterange'),
                                 br()
                                 
                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 dataTableOutput('table'),
                                 br(), br(), 
                                 downloadButton("dl", "Download")
                               ),
                             ))
  ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  data <- reactive(Test)
  
  output$daterange <- renderUI({
    tagList(dateRangeInput("daterange1", "Period you want to see:",
                           min   = min(data()$date2),
                           max   = max(data()$date2),
                           
                           tags$script(HTML('
                setTimeout(function(){
                  $("#daterange1 input")[0].value = "No date selected";
                  $("#daterange1 input")[1].value = "No date selected";
                }, 50);
            '))))
            })
    
    data_subset <- reactive({
      req(input$daterange1)
      req(input$daterange1[1] < input$daterange1[2])
      days <- seq(input$daterange1[1], input$daterange1[2], by = 'day')
      subset(data(), date2 %in% days)
    })
    
    
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      data_subset()
    })
    
    output$dl <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() { "data.xlsx"},
      content = function(file) {
        writexl::write_xlsx(data_subset(), path = file)
      }
    )
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno! Just one question: Why I choose the start date appears: `Error: 'to' must be a finite number`? Is it possible to adjust this so that this error does not appear?

Comment: This happens because both start and end need to make be present for the rest of the code to work and you only checked for input$daterange1 not for the values being picked, if this is going to be further checked start can never be bigger than end as well

Comment: I understand, but there is no way to make this error not appear in Shiny when choosing.

Comment: You can make as many reqs as you desire

Comment: I added the req for bigger values for example, you can think of more error checking measures case by case

Comment: Thank you very much Bruno!